# VBA Problem with find some data and copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The macro stopped working for me, I don't know why, it should copy data from data_wb.Sheets to wbMe. data_wb should run in the shade. There is no error, however, the data is not looking, as if it would not know in which tab. should in "Adekwatnosc" someone knows why? when I go after f8, it jumps straight away "Set loc = .Cells.Find (what: = vDate)
If Not loc Is Nothing Then do to end if "
It looks like nothing could be found in the Adekwatnosc sheet.

```
Sub PlanKroczacyRefresh()


Dim vDate As Date
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim data_wb As Workbook
Dim inputbx As String
Dim loc As Range, lc As Long
Dim MyFolder As String, ThisMonth As String
Dim MyFile As String

'Zmieniamy nagłówek na short date w pliku z makrem'

Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook
With wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Rows("1:1")
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
  End With
  
'Otwieramy plik automatycznie ze wskazanego folderu'
  

MyFolder = "C:\Users\V1410190\Documents\FOLDERY ROBOCZE"


MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\Kopia PKO BH Plan kroczac1*.xlsm")


If MyFile <> "" Then

Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

Else
Exit Sub
End If

'Usuwamy alerty o akutliazacji itp'
Application.ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever '2
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

'Zmieniamy nagłówek na short date w pliku z planem kroczącym'

With data_wb.Sheets("Adekwatnosc").Rows("1:1")
   .Value = .Value
   .NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
End With
'input box - wpisujemy date zgodnie z podanym formatem'
 Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD", Format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        vDate = DateValue(inputbx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(vDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid
       
' Wyszukujemy find daty w nagłówku -> kopiujemy -> wklejamy je do pliku z makrem we wskazane w makrze miejscu'
     
data_wb.Worksheets("Adekwatnosc").Activate
     With data_wb.Worksheets("Adekwatnosc")
        Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            lc = .Cells(loc.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(109, loc.Column), .Cells(123, lc)).Copy
      Set locPaste = wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells(27, locPaste.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      
      lc1 = .Cells(loc.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(138, loc.Column), .Cells(138, lc1)).Copy
      Set locPaste = wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells(21, locPaste.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      
      
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: if nothing in the code has changed, then it's probably the path to the workbooks or the worksheet names.  check to make sure you have the file C:\Users\V1410190\Documents\FOLDERY ROBOCZE\Kopia PKO BH Plan kroczac1*.xlsm and it has a sheet named "Adekwatnosc and also check that the active workbook has a sheet named "input_forecast"

Comment: `.Cells.Find (what: = vDate)` - here you provide only the "what to look for" argument to `Find()`: there are other parameters such as `LookIn`, `LookAt`, etc which can affect whether you get the match you're expecting.  These settings are "sticky" and remembered from any previous use of `Find()` (via code or manual).  It's best to explicitly provide _all_ of the arguments which might affect the outcome.

Comment: @TimWilliams are you mean .Cells.Find () ? remove vdate. Maybe its some wrong with inputx box and vdate ? how to create input box witout date format just only string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim vDate As Date, loc As Range, data_wb As Workbook, inputbx
    Dim DateIsValid As Boolean, lc As Long
    
    Set data_wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    With data_wb.Sheets("Adekwatnosc").Rows("1:1")
       .Value = .Value
       .NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    End With
    
    Do
        'note user does not need to follow your format to enter a valid date
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD", Format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        If IsDate(inputbx) Then
            vDate = DateValue(inputbx)
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
            vDate = 0
        End If
    Loop While vDate = 0
           
    With data_wb.Worksheets("Adekwatnosc")
        'specify all relevant arguments to Find().  Note *xlFormulas* for dates
        Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=vDate, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
        If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Found at " & loc.Address
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```