# How can I select the cell of a user input date when dates are in formulas in my worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Below an extremely simplified version of my code for testing. I want to get a date from a user input, search along A:A of the ratesheet and then select that cell. Ideally, I'd like to offset from that cell by one so I can paste something. However, I keep getting an error that the object variable is not set. I don't see any issues setting variables. The date exists in the worksheet (I tested with CTRL + F using the same string). I'm not sure what's going on.

```
Sub SelectDateTest()
    Dim SDate As Date
    Dim finder As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ratesheet As Worksheet
    Dim IRS As Workbook
        
    Set IRS = ThisWorkbook
    Set ratesheet = IRS.Worksheets("Historical Rates")
    
    With Application
        SDate = CDate(.InputBox(Prompt:="enter startdate mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=2))
    End With
    
    
    finder = Format(SDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
   

    Set rng = ratesheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=finder, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    MsgBox finder & " found in " & rng.Address

    
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried finding `SDate` instead of `finder`?

Comment: Oddly, it was not working and then I found something here that recommended using a string. Now, I go back to using the date and it works fine. I guess I corrected other issues and now it'll work fine. Thanks!

Comment: It's so common for `Find` to fail that I always check to see if the result is `Not Nothing` before proceeding. Even if the problem has been resolved, I suggest checking `If Not rng Is Nothing Then ...` before you proceed with the rest of the macro.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to `Select` a range from a different sheet, make sure to `Activate` the parent sheet first, otherwise you get an error.

Comment: In a previous similar post I found that using `Lookin:=xlFormulas` was more consitent when searching for a date:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367451/vba-problem-with-find-some-data-and-copy-to-another-sheet/70386159#70386159